# Execute and finish of methods

Tags: c++

This is a very naive question, please forgive my ignorance if I use the wrong terms.

If I have a series of instructions as in the snippet,

```
bool methodComplete = false;
methodComplete = doSomeMethod(someParam, etcParam); //long & complex method that returns true
if (methodComplete)
   doSomeOtherMethod();
```

will the method `doSomeMethod()` finish its execution before `if (methodComplete)` is evaluated?

Or is this a case for an asynchronous pattern if I want to guarantee it is completed?

Comment: What you probably want for an asynchronous scenario is [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) and [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). You should clarify your question a bit.

Comment: The calculation of methodComplete will have finished. The cpu is free to execute other instructions out of order if they don't affect that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language specifications define how a program will effectively behave from the point of the user/programmer. So, yes, you can assume that the program behaves as that:

- It computes `doSomeMethod`
- It stores the results in `methodComplete`
- It executes the if clauses

That said, some optimizations *might* result in code executed ahead, see [Speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution).

Answer (score 1):

> will the method `doSomeMethod()` finished executing before `if (methodComplete)` is evaluated?

Yes<sup>*</sup>.

> or is this a case for an asynchronous pattern if I want to guarantee it has completed?

Only if you are doing parallel computing.

---

<sup>*)</sup><sub>It can get to be a no if your code is executing in parallel..</sub>

Comment: thanks @gsamaras for your explanation, it did answer my question but I could only choose one answer